# Is it possible to have social login without Hosted UI in Amazon Cognito?

Tags: ios, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to understand if Amazon Cognito can fit our needs, it seems a nice service but I cannot find any documentation that explains how to implement the authentication flow without using the User Pools hosted UI on a Native Mobile App. Right now we managed to do that with email/password but we are not able to do the same with Facebook social login.

So my question is: we use Facebook SDK to get a user's Facebook access token and then? Can I receive a cognito authorization code without using the hosted UI? How?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey, did you figure something out?

Comment: No, we switched to Firebase Authentication

Answer (score 4):

You can authenticate directly to Federated apps, by redirecting to this,

`https://' + domain + '/authorize?identity_provider=' + provider + '&response_type=' + type + '&client_id=' + clientId + '&redirect_uri=' + callback + '&state=' + '&scope=' + scope`

here is a sample which I follow in my VueJS app. https://github.com/PaulMaddox/aws-vuejs-cognito/blob/master/src/services/auth.js#L19

Not sure how to do the same in iOS.